# How much overhead would Mongoose add to the node-mongodb-native driver?

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

How much overhead does Mongoose add to the node-mongodb-native driver? If I just wanted to have a couple structurally similar queries on several collections, would it make more sense to just write everything using the driver directly? For example, I would need to do something as follows (in the driver language, as copied from [here](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/examples/queries.js)):

```
db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {
  collection.find({'a':1}, function(err, cursor) {
    *do something*
  }
}
```

Where I would just replace `'test'` and `'a'` with variables to hold the actual collection and key that I'm looking for.

I feel like it makes sense in this case to just write everything using the driver directly. Would there be any reason to use Mongoose itself? Is the overhead so negligible that I'm being silly by considering using the driver directly?

Best, and thanks,
Sami

Comment: So I couldn't test mongoose and mongo-db-native-driver but mongose code is around 150 kb. It's quite large. And that's the reason to use it pure.

Comment: Filesize doesn't really matter as much on the server as it does in the client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how large your app is going to be.  If you're only doing a few queries it's probably not worth adding Mongoose to the mix but once your app starts to grow Mongoose can help keep it more maintainable. Dev time is usually more valuable than processing time.

Unless your app is going to be serving a LOT of simultaneous requests you probably won't notice the difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Another good thing about using Mongoose is that you clearly define your Models (including defaults, validation, etc) up-front in your application, which both provides a lot of intrinsic documentation for your application, and dramatically reduces the possibility of inconsistencies when you deal with a relatively unstructured data model.

Relational databases have a lot of features for defining data types, defaults, indexes, etc. and will throw errors if you (for example) try and use a column that doesn't exist.

Mongo removes a lot of that overhead but it creates more work ensuring that a consistent data model is documented and maintained in the implementation code; Mongoose makes it a lot easier.

It also has a lot of useful features to keep your models in check, including an option to use strict Schemas (on by default as of v3) which means any values you haven't already defined don't get written to the database, 'virtual fields', which for example could combine first name and last name into a string as if it were stored in the database (but it doesn't have to be), and index management. For more details see [the guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).